# Push notifications to Android (and iOS)

Tags: android, ios, .net, push-notification

I'm looking for a non "cloud" push notifications framework that will allow us to push notifications from our servers to mobile devices (mainly Android and iOS is optional).
Using cloud services it not possible since both the server and the client can be in a local network without internet connectivity.
Is there any framework we can use (server side is .NET)?

Thanks

Comment: "since both the server and the client can be in a local network without internet connectivity" -- keeping the CPU and WiFi on continuously to listen for messages means that the battery life will be fairly poor. At least on Android, the reason why GCM can work with decent battery life is that it uses mobile data connections, with some carefully-tuned code to allow the CPU (and WiFi) to fall asleep while still maintaining those connections.

Comment: Yes you can do that, for local server you can use something like [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com) and then you can use [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) which solves the client side problems like no internet connection. :D There are lots tutorials out there to do this, google it or even better, just search Push notifications using GCM on stackoverflow :D

Comment: Any solutions for iOS will only work while your app is running in the foreground (if this is an enterprise app, not an App Store app then you could use VOIP background mode)

Answer (score 0):

For iOS this is not possible since every notification has to go through Apple's push notification server. More details on that can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html).

One thing you could do is using the [Background Fetch](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html) feature introduced in iOS 7 to repeatedly poll a server in the background and show Local Notifications in case anything new has been found in the server. This wouldn't be instantaneous though but rather have any indeterminate time lag.